# AWS ECS - Rails Container is not able to connect linked container mysql via mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql, docker, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I have setup application on AWS ECS , with repository, task and cluster management. 
My `Dockerfile` is

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs \
                       vim \
                       mysql-client --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


WORKDIR /tmp
ADD ./Gemfile Gemfile
ADD ./Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

ENV APP_ROOT /workspace
RUN mkdir -p $APP_ROOT
WORKDIR $APP_ROOT
COPY . $APP_ROOT

EXPOSE  3000
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-e", "production"]
```

This is a repository which I have set up on the AWS ECS repository.

In the task destination I have set up two containers `rail-app` and `mysql`, which are `linked` to each other

From the `rails-app`, I am trying to connect `RDS` mysql instance, but as its throwing following error, I have added `mysql` container to support the connection which I think is not required as well

When I run the application with added task in the cluster `service` . Both containers runs fine, But on the `rails-app` container I got this error.

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)`

When I run `rails c production` under `docker exec -it containerid bash` it runs fine and connects db properly. Here I can test active records as well

Please provide me a solution in task destination to share volume of mysql to rails application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here,

I have assigned env variables on the container section of task. Which were not loaded properly on the environment. When I have used `figaro` with `application.yml` It has started using variables as per the environment.

Mysql was not able to get the host from environment